# Describe the set of Kripke scales

Tags: logic, model-theory, modal-logic, kripke-models

Describe the set of Kripke scales in which the formula $\square(\square p \to p) \to \square p$. is generally valid.

it seems that this is just a set of scales in which a loop necessarily comes out of every vertex except the root one (if there is one), but is this so?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: What do you mean by ‘loop’? This formula is valid in exactly the transitive and conversely-well founded frames.

Comment: @PW_246 I mean, if we have a connectedness relation R(a,b) in the scale, then R(x,x) must be fulfilled for any vertex x

Comment: @PW_246 what is conversely-well founded frames? And im not sure that it is about transitive frames, can you please add the proof of this fact

Comment: @Quark converse-well foundedness just means that there is no infinite ascending chain of worlds $w_{0}Rw_{1}R…$. As such, it must be that $wRw$ holds for no world $w$, since then the infinite chain $wRwRw…$ would exist. Note that the transitivity axiom $\Box p \to \Box \Box p $ is provable since $\Box (p \to (\Box (p \land \Box p) \to (p \land \Box p)))$ is a theorem of system K.

Comment: @PW_246 But why can't it be infinitely ascending? And I don't understand at all where this theorem came from and why the law of transitivity follows from it

Comment: See here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/